# Use different language than locale for strftime by perl script

Tags: perl, strftime

My OS is in polish language. I need print month name in english by perl script.

Locale:

```
LANG=pl_PL.UTF8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF8"
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF8"
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use POSIX;

print strftime "%b %d, %Y", gmtime(time());
```

Output: `kwi 11, 2018`
Expected: `Mar 11, 2018`

Is there any smarter solution than do `s/kwi/Mar/`?

Comment: *Not* tested: `{local $ENV{LC_ALL}='C'; print strftime "%b %d, %Y", gmtime;}`

Comment: See also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/karupanerura/2027343).

Comment: [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) defaults to `en-US` unless explicitly changed: `use DateTime; print DateTime->now->strftime("%b %d, %Y");` prints `Apr 12, 2018`.

Answer (score 4):

POSIX::setlocale is what you need

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use POSIX qw(setlocale strftime);
print strftime "%a %b %d, %Y", gmtime(time());
setlocale(POSIX::LC_ALL,'en_US.utf8');
print strftime "%a %b %d, %Y", gmtime(time());
setlocale(&POSIX::LC_ALL,'de_DE.utf8');
print strftime "%a %b %d, %Y", gmtime(time());
```

[perldoc POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) should give additional info. Also see [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#The-setlocale-function) about setting and resetting the locale.